# "Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function" error occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been developing a navigation bar. I wrote a function to switch screens and call it in button onClick. I wrapped the component in `withRouter` also. But the following error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function" error.

This is my code:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navigation(history) {
  const abc = path => {
    history.push(path);
  };

return(
<button onClick={() => abc('/user')}>User</button>
);}

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

Thank you

Comment: It maybe `function Navigation({history})`.

Answer (score 14):

## Per `react-router-dom` v5 → v6 migration

The old `useHistory` has been replaced by `useNavigate`

> @see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Old v5 code:

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();
history.push(`/Search?${queryString}`);
```

New v6 code:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(`/Search?${queryString}`);
```

Comment: Such a savior! Thank you! Was so confused and wasting so much time on such a simple thing. Thanks so much for the `useNavigate()`, was able to get my material-ui buttons rendering an `<a>` and also changing path as desired :)

Answer (score 8):

You have wrapped the `Navigation` component with `withRouter`, thus you will need to access the history object via the component's props. You may choose to destructure your props as shown below:

```
function Navigation({ history }) {
  const abc = path => {
    history.push(path);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => abc('/user')}>User</button>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

Since you are working with functional components, an alternative way of doing things would be to make use of the `useHistory` hook, which spares you the need to wrap your component with `withRouter`:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navigation(props) {
  const history = useHistory();

  const abc = path => {
    history.push(path);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => abc('/user')}>User</button>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it works for me.
Using `history(path)` instead of `history.push(path)`

```
function NavItem1(props) { //Navigate to the home page
  const history = useNavigate();

  const redirect = path => {
    history(path);
  };

  return (  
    <a href="#"  className="icon-button" onClick={() => redirect('/')} >
    {props.icon}
  </a>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to destruct all the props like `Navigation({ history })`

Answer (score 0):

For [umi](https://umijs.org/api) users, we should add this:

```js
import { history } from 'umi';
```