# history.push error with Typescript & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working with React and TypeScript.
Here is my problem:
When I try to do a history.push, it returns an error like this:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: history.push is not a function

Here is my code:

```js
interface Props extends 
WithTranslation {
  history: any;
}

const Menu: React.FC<Props> = ({
  history
}) => {
  if (await MarketplaceRequests.sessionsTest()) {
      history.push({
        pathname: '/',
      });
  }

return ......
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe this has been answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082869/uncaught-typeerror-history-push-is-not-a-function-error-occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in react-router-dom v6 useHistory doesn't work or its deprecated. Instead use `useNavigate`:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()

const Menu: React.FC<Props> = ({
  navigate
}) => {
  if (await MarketplaceRequests.sessionsTest()) {
      navigate('/');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React Router Dom > v6, you need to use useNavigate.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/route');
```

However, if not, you need to import `useHistory` as same as useNavigate in the example above.